# How to authenticate users through direct bind in django with multiple ldap servers, multiple domains

Tags: django, authentication, dns, active-directory

I am a new-bee in Python and django. I searched a lot but could not find a satisfying solution for my below situation.

The company has different ldap servers(microsoft I think) for different domains. User login form has username, password and domain. I need to authenticate credentials from the server based on his domain selection. I know which server to use for a given domain. I do not have admin login and password to do ldap search. So I would rather like to use ldap direct bind.

Given the situation I would like to ask "How to authenticate users against multiple ldap server with different domains using ldap direct bind". Any help would be appreciated.

I am trying myself to find the solution. I will post it if I get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the solution to my specific problem. Would be useful to someone with problem similar to mine.

settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
#'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
'rango.auth.SettingsBackend',
'rango.auth.CustomLdapBackend',

)

ADMIN_CREDENTIALS = {
    'admin':'pbkdf2_sha256$12000$btzDXMsGghKq$Bv1GasiWFSJXQUn7J4gHCzJVubm9ZAHfiMaVNdblo9Y=',
}
AUTH_LDAP_SERVERS = {
    'DOMAIN-1':{'URI':'123.4.56.78', 'DN':'dc=bla,dc=bla,dc=com',},
    'DOMAIN-2':{'URI':'123.4.56.79', 'DN':'dc=blue,dc=blue,dc=com',},
    'DOMAIN-3':{'URI':'123.4.56.77', 'DN':'dc=black,dc=vblack,dc=com',},
}
```

foo/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    domain = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
#
```

foo/auth.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, check_password
from rango.models import UserProfile
import ldap
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
#


class Backend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, domain=None):
        pass
    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user_by_username(self,username):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(username=username)
        except:
            return None
#


class LdapBackend(Backend):
    def _get_ldap_user_by_username(self, conn, username, dn):
        try:
            search_scope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
            retrieve_attributes = None
            search_filter = "samaccountname="+username
            result_id = conn.search(dn,search_scope,search_filter,retrieve_attributes)
            result_set = []
            ldap_user = {}
            while 1:
                result_type, result_data = conn.result(result_id,0)
                if (result_data ==[]):
                    break
                else:
                    if result_type == ldap.RES_SEARCH_ENTRY:
                        result_set.append(result_data)

            ldap_user = result_set[0][0][1]
            return ldap_user
        except:
            return {}
#


class CustomLdapBackend(LdapBackend):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, domain=None):
        try:
            credentials = [username, password, domain]
            if (None in credentials) or ('' in credentials):
                return None

            if domain not in settings.AUTH_LDAP_SERVERS:
                return None

            ldap.set_option( ldap.OPT_REFERRALS,0 )
            try:
                conn = ldap.initialize('ldap://'+ settings.AUTH_LDAP_SERVERS[domain]['URI'])
                conn.simple_bind_s( username + '@' + domain, password )
            except:
                conn.unbind_s()
                return None

            user = self.get_user_by_username( username=username )

            if user is None:
                user = User(username=username, password='')
                user.save()
                user = self.get_user_by_username(username)
                ldap_user = self._get_ldap_user_by_username(conn=conn, 
                        username=username,dn= settings.AUTH_LDAP_SERVERS[domain]['DN']
                    )

                if ldap_user is not None:
                    try:
                        user.first_name = ldap_user['givenName'][0]
                    except:
                        pass
                    try:
                        user.last_name = ldap_user['sn'][0]
                    except:
                        pass
                    try:
                        user.email = ldap_user['mail'][0]
                    except:
                        pass
                user.save()
                user = self.get_user_by_username(username=username)
                user_profile = UserProfile(user=user, domain=domain)
                user_profile.save()
                user = self.get_user_by_username(username=username)
            conn.unbind_s()

            if str(user.userprofile.domain) != domain:
                return None

            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            return user
        except:
            return None
#


class SettingsBackend(Backend):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, domain=None ):

        try:
            if username not in settings.ADMIN_CREDENTIALS :
                return None

            if check_password(password, settings.ADMIN_CREDENTIALS[username]):
                user = self.get_user_by_username(username = username)
                if user is None:
                    # create one
                    user = User(username=username, password= settings.ADMIN_CREDENTIALS[username])
                    user.is_staff = True
                    user.is_superuser = True
                    user.save()
                return user
            return None
        except:
            return None
#
```

/foo/login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>foo</title></head>

    <body>
        <h1>Login to foo</h1>

        <form id="login_form" method="post" action="/foo/login/" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />
        <br/>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" size="50" />
        <br/>
        Domain: <select id="domain" name="domain">
            <option selected value="DOMAIN-1">DOMAIN-1</option>
            <option value="DOMAIN-2">DOMAIN-2</option>
            <option value="DOMAIN-3">DOMAIN-3</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

foo/views.py

```
def user_login(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        domain = request.POST.get('domain', None )
        user = authenticate( username=username, password=password, domain=domain )

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                print request.user.id
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/foo/')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Your fooaccount is disabled.")
        else:
            print "Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password)
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")
    else:
        return render_to_response('foo/login.html', {}, context)
#
```

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to ignore the domain, use the [multiple-backend](https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/multiconfig.html) feature of django-auth-ldap, and just let it try each one until it succeeds. That's rather unsatisfying, of course. With a little custom code, you should be able to do this right:

```
from django_auth_ldap import LDAPBackend


class LDAPDomainBackend(LDAPBackend):
    domain = None

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, domain=None):
        if None in [username, password, domain]:
            return None

        if domain == self.domain:
            user = super(LDAPDomainBackend, self).authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        else:
            user = None

        return user

class DomainFooBackend(LDAPDomainBackend):
    settings_prefix = 'AUTH_LDAP_FOO_'
    domain = 'foo'


class DomainBarBackend(LDAPDomainBackend):
    settings_prefix = 'AUTH_LDAP_BAR_'
    domain = 'bar'
```

settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'path.to.DomainFooBackend',
    'path.to.DomainBarBackend',
]


AUTH_LDAP_FOO_SERVER_URI = 'ldap://foo.example.com'
AUTH_LDAP_FOO_USER_DN_TEMPLATE = '...'

AUTH_LDAP_BAR_SERVER_URI = 'ldap://bar.example.com'
AUTH_LDAP_BAR_USER_DN_TEMPLATE = '...'
```

Comment: I appreciate your efforts taken to guide me. I tried above method but did not work. On debugging I found that its getting domain as None in authenticate method. How do I make sure the correct domain is sent to this method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Django's default authentication form only expects username and password. You'll probably want to write your own authentication form class and pass it to django.contrib.auth.views.login. And/or just write your own login view. One way or another, someone needs to end up calling django.contrib.auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password, domain=domain).

Comment: i tried your suggestion but some how i could not make it work.